# Выборка данных двух столбцов таблицы с разными условиями по другой таблице

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет! Второй день пытаюсь написать запрос один SELECT запрос к таблице. Есть таблица которая "Menu", которая содержит id нескольких блюд на день.

```
id | dayOfWeek | first | firstPrice | second | secondPrice
----------------------------------------------------------
1  |    0      |   2   |    70      |   3    |   50
2  |    1      |   1   |    60      |   2    |   70
```

И есть таблица "Courses", которая содержит название блюда и его id.

```
id | name
---------
1  | fish
2  | chiken
3  | beef
```

И соответственно мне нужно вывести вот примерно такую таблицу:
where dayOfWeek = 0

```
first | firstPrice | second | secondPrice
-----------------------------------------
chiken|     70     |  beef  |   50
```

т.е. заменить id на название из второй таблицы. Думаю, что тут нужен либо цикл, либо джойнить, но как это делать в одной таблице по одному столбцу, разобраться не получается!

Comment: Почему в тегах одновременно указаны СУБД и от Oracle и от Microsoft? Уберите лишнее

Comment: Нормализуйте структуру. Потом будете думать о написании запросов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если с одной таблицей нужно соединиться несколько раз, то делается несколько JOIN, а таблицам даются разные псевдонимы. В данном случае F для first и S для second.

```
SELECT
  F.name as first,
  M.firstPrice,
  S.name as second,
  M.secondPrice
FROM menu M
JOIN Courses F on F.id = M.first
JOIN Courses S on S.id = M.second
```

WHERE уже сами допишите.

PS использован синтаксис Microsoft SQL Server, так как он тоже указан в тегах.